# Xcode JSON how to get data into format i can use

Tags: objective-c, json

I am trying to get data from a server.

The data when viewing it in a web browser looks like this:

```
["IAP000000_1","IAP000000_2","IAP000000_7","IAP000000_8"]
```

What I'm trying to do is convert the JSON NSData to an NSArray but have no idea how. Can anyone help? My code is listened below, also if I can improve the code below please say, I have been trying to get head around the internet examples for far to long now.

Thanks

```
+ (void) GetProductIdentifiers
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* kivaData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                            [NSURL URLWithString:@"blah blah"]
                            ];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self ReturnArray: kivaData];
        });

    });
}

+ (NSArray*) ReturnArray:(NSData*)json{
    //Convert data here from json to nsarray
}
```

Comment: Do some basic investigation of how to parse JSON.  The above is a JSON array, which will parse directly into an NSArray.  Do your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+ (NSArray*) ReturnArray:(NSData*)json{
    //Convert data here from json to nsarray

    NSError *jsonError;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
    if (jsonError)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", jsonError.description);
        return nil;
    }

    return jsonArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is serialize the NSData into JSON:

```
NSArray *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:kivaData 
                                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                  error:nil];

for (NSString * iap in data) {
    NSLog(@"iap = %@", iap);
}
```